# mulitple line labeling arcgis

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling, vbscript

I try to label a field according to his length with VBScripting in ArcGIS 10.0

The idea is, if my field is more than a certain length, then please add a new line and split the field correctly.  My field can be Null.

I can't get the code below  to work (Verify returns nothing):

`Function FindLabel ( [JOIN_NUMBER] )
If IsNull([JOIN_NUMBER] ) Then
FindLabel = [JOIN_NUMBER] 
Else 
FindLabel = Left([JOIN_NUMBER] ,8) & vbnewline & Right([JOIN_NUMBER] ,Len([JOIN_NUMBER] ,-8))
End If
End Function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
Right([JOIN_NUMBER],Len([JOIN_NUMBER])-8))
```

Comment: That's it. Also my condition was wrong because I have also not Null fields that were < 8 caracters long. So they "disappear" because of the else statment. Great now :)